# passing values from applet to jsp

Tags: java, jsp, applet

```
import java.awt.*; 
import java.applet.*;

public class GuiExample extends Applet { 
    Button okButton; 
    TextField nameField;

    public void init() { 
        setLayout(null); 
        okButton = new Button("A button"); 
        nameField = new TextField("A TextField",100); 
        okButton.setBounds(20,20,100,30); 
        nameField.setBounds(20,70,100,40); 

        add(okButton); 
        add(nameField); 
    }

}
```

how can i pass the value in the textbox to the 'validate.jsp', when the button is clicked?
And i also want the browser to go to that jsp page. and continue execution from there?
How can i modify the code?

Comment: You need to add your own `ActionListener` implementation to the Button, which reads the value from the TextField and then calls `this.getAppletContext().showDocument(new URL("validate.jsp?p="+textFieldValue))` (eventually you need to URL-encode the field value).

Comment: @jCoder: Why don't you post this as an answer? I think it is all that is necessary.

Comment: @Paŭlo I actually left out many implementation details. I'll post a complete answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

This bit of code might be helpful.

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.net.*;

public class GuiExample extends Applet { 
    Button okButton; 
    TextField nameField;
    GuiExample currentApplet; // needed for navigation

    public void init() {
        currentApplet = this;
        setLayout(null); 
        okButton = new Button("A button"); 
        nameField = new TextField("A TextField",100); 
        okButton.setBounds(20,20,100,30); 
        nameField.setBounds(20,70,100,40); 

        add(okButton); 
        add(nameField);

        okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String text = nameField.getText();
                if (text != null) {
                    try {
                        // modify this to point to your website
                        String address = "http://www.example.com/validate.jsp?p=" + URLEncoder.encode(text, "UTF-8");
                        currentApplet.getAppletContext().showDocument(new URL(address));
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

}